# Elif is giving error and also line 10 says an unexpected indent

Tags: python, syntax-error

Below is the full code I have been working on creating a game from a book by Eric Matthes Chapter 12 and it is showing errors for line 5 and line 10:

```
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet
def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Fire a bullet if limit not reached yet."""
        # Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group.
        if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
            bullets.add(new_bullet)
def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
            """Respond to keypresses."""
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                # Move the ship to the right.
                ship.moving_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                check_keyup_events(event, ship)
        def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
            """Respond to key releases."""
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ship.moving_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = False
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw all bullets behind ship and aliens.
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()
    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()
def update_bullets(bullets):
    """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
    # Update bullet positions.
    bullets.update()
    # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
```

You are using elif without if. It is invalid

Also this line `if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:` has an indentation error.

Comment: how do i solve it because in the book it doesnt show any 'if' for the elif part and how do I fix the indentation error.

Comment: You can change ```elif``` to ```if```